# mysql/mariadb import sql file, comments not imported

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've got an SQL file that I export which contains the structure, stored procedures and data.  I'm developing a C++ application that I use to create the exported file, it now has an import feature, however when I import the data with:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=trainer --password=Secret <trainer.sql
```

The SQL file contains comments in the stored procedures, these comments are within the BEGIN - END scope, but when the import has completed and I look at the database (using HeidiSQL) I can see blank areas where the comments should be but no comments.

I've searched online for this and the only thing I could see was a mention to ensure the comments are within the BEGIN - END scope which they are.

The database is **MariaDB 10.5.9.0**, running on **Windows 10**.  If I use HeidiSQL to import the same file it works perfectly and the comments are present so it has to be something I've omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `mysql` client ignores all comments in SQL. Use the `-c` or `--comments` flag to include them.

> -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server.
> The
> default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
> with --comments.